# Android how to add more than one ContentProvider in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

1. Is this possible to use more than one ContentProvider?
2. If possible how to declare in manifest? I tried using following way but `getContentResolver()` is getting only the first provider.

   ```
       <provider
           android:name=".bean.ItemBean"
           android:authorities="com.waveletandroid.bean" >
       </provider>

      <provider
           android:name=".bean.CustomerBean"
           android:authorities="com.waveletandroid.bean" >
       </provider>
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this possible to use more than one ContentProvider?

Yes. Or, you can have one `ContentProvider` that provides multiple data sets, based upon the path portion of the `Uri` or via different authorities.

> If possible how to declare in manifest?

What you have is almost correct. They cannot both have the same authority, though. Change one to be something else (e.g., `com.waveletandroid.bean2`).